# How can I remove the iFrame widget border in Slate?

Tags: iframe, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I have an IFrame widget in Slate, and it has a gray border around it as in the screenshot below. I want to embed the IFrame in my app, but I need the format to fit more seamlessly into the rest of the app. I have tried looking in the styles tab without success. Is it possible to remove this border?[image: IFrame with example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border can be removed using CSS:

```
iframe {
   border: none; 
}
```

Just paste this code snippet into the Custom Styles field in the widget settings.
[image: Show where to enter code]